# Contact Form Emails not displaying on IOS devices

Tags: php, email, linux, ios, apple

I'm having an issue that appears to be localized to IOS devices, those, particularly that use the default mail client.
Emails are sent to these clients automatically through their website contact forms.
And when viewed, the message body reads:

"The message cannot be displayed because a problem occurred."

The email subject and headers appear to be all good with valid DKIM signatures and formatting.
If I use a 3rd party application like JotForm, they come in without issue.
My question is how do these other mail clients not have this issue?

Things I have tried.

Sending header content-types as text/plain, text/html, multipart/alternative, multipart/form-data.

Even a hardcoded PHP mail function does not work.
e.g.

```
mail("test@email.com", "test subject", "hardcoded message body");
```

Additionally, it should be mentioned that checking our email spam scores using mail-tester.com are very high and are not being triggered as spam.
Finally, I've called Apple Business Support and they said it's a known issue as of December 6th, but didn't give me any details as to what and why it's happening.

Has anyone experienced this issue and if so how did you resolve it?

Environment Specs: LAMP stack sending mail using Exim

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **web development** which is off-topic at Pro Webmasters. Web development questions may be asked at [so] but be sure to read their [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help) before posting to ensure your question meets their guidelines.